# diff_match_patch: Generating side-by-side view

Tags: java, diff

I'm using [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) with my Java app to create a diff. I use the method diff_prettyHtml for generating HTML output of the diff.

However, I would like to have two different outputs, so I can put them side-by-side to make it a bit more easy for the user to see the differences. (For example, like Eclipse does.)

Is there anything in that library I can use to achieve this? How would *you* do that? (I would not use a different library, if possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not attempting to diff HTML, in which case I'd suggest using [DaisyDiff](http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/), what you probably want to do with diff-match-patch is [line differencing, which is described on a project wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/LineOrWordDiffs). Basically it involves generating an array of hash codes, one for each line of the left and right, and keeping track of those hash codes relative to the lines in a map, and then running those arrays through the diffing algorithm. Then you use the diff output in conjunction with the map to rehydrate left and right highlighting as appropriate.

Comment: BTW, I wrote a wrapper library to help with the "presentation work" needed to use `diff_match_patch`: https://github.com/arnab/jQuery.PrettyTextDiff

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to implement a different approach in Python:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577784-line-based-side-by-side-diff/

Failing test cases are welcome.